# This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback..Whiteable Error page

Tags: spring-boot

> I am started bulding a spring boot application  but iam getting this
>   type of error This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so
>   you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Jun 17 21:38:33 IST 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available
>   [image: It got in my browser]
>
> This is my project strcture
>   [image: project strcture]
>
> Devlopoment.java

```
package com.main.devlopment;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DevlopmentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DevlopmentApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

> UserController.java

```
package com.main.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.main.dao.UsersRepository;
import com.main.model.UsersModel;

@RestController
public class UsersController {
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usprepo;

    @RequestMapping("/Users")
    public List<UsersModel> getUsers(){
        return usprepo.findAll();
    }

}
```

> UserRepository.java

```
package com.main.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.main.model.UsersModel;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<UsersModel, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Try moving `DevlopmentApplication.java` class to `package com.main` from `package com.main.devlopment`

Comment: I try this trick but it show me another error  cannot find userrepo bean in my controller class